# Protobuf and Pipeline questions

Tags: protocol-buffers, netty

Is there any way to set more than one protobufEncoder/protobufDecoder?

Let me explain my problem.I have a command which will be send from the
client to the server,The server get the command and do some work according
to the command.Now the response ("answer") of the server could be:
for the length of string or is for the integer square (order not sure)

My question is now:what can I do that the client can receive at least two
different responses from the server? Both are "encoded" with Protobuf.And 
in turn,what I need to do that the server can send at least two different 
responses?Also both are "encoded" with Protobuf.both are "decoder" with protobuf.

ProtobufDecoder of netty to set two different protobufEncoder/Decoder is not possible.

Let us see below netty example, decoder can only receive a decoder object

LocalTimeServerPipelineFactory:

```
public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() throws Exception {
    ChannelPipeline p = pipeline();
    p.addLast("frameDecoder", new ProtobufVarint32FrameDecoder());
    p.addLast("protobufDecoder", new ProtobufDecoder(LocalTimeProtocol.Locations.getDefaultInstance()));

    p.addLast("frameEncoder", new ProtobufVarint32LengthFieldPrepender());
    p.addLast("protobufEncoder", new ProtobufEncoder());

    p.addLast("handler", new LocalTimeServerHandler());
    return p;
}
```

thanks in advance and best regards.

quartz

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the ChannelPipeline on the fly. This should help you there. Just add/remove the right one when you need it.

Comment: If I wrap the protobuf messages with an envelope protocol.  For example:

<TYPE> <LENGTH> <PROTOBUFDATA>
 .Add a encoder and decoder, the purpose of which is to protobufEncoder and protobufDecoder add a message head. 
How do you feel?